# max f$( (a,b) )$= max $f( [a,b] )$ in continuous function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and gets its maximum in $(a,b)$.
Prove that max $f( (a,b) )$= max $f( [a,b] )$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to formulate your questions. Also, do you have any thoughts on the given problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, or just using calculus?

Comment: It is clear that $\max_{x \in [a,b]} f(x) \ge \max_{x \in (a,b)} f(x) $. You are given that $f(a),f(b)$ are no greater than $ \max_{x \in (a,b)} f(x) $.

Comment: @Moriah I think it's something using "Extreme value theorem" but I don't really have any ideas about this question, it's something that very simple that I just don't know how to prove :(

Comment: @copper.hat I don't really think that It's what they want when it says "prove". I cant just write it's clear in my homework :D

Comment: Try convincing yourself why it is clear then

Comment: It is straightforward to prove that if $A \subset B$ and $\max A, \max B$ exist, then $\max A \le \max B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c \in (a,b)$ be the point where $f$ attains its maximum in $(a,b)$. Assume $f(a)>\max(f((a,b)))$ (i.e. $f(a)=\max(f((a,b)))+d$ for some $d>0$), and then use the Intermediate Value Theorem on the interval $[a,c]$ to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume hat $f(a)>\max_{x\in(a,b)}f(x)=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in(a,b)$.

Such $x_0$ exists since $f$ gets its maximum at $(a,b)$.

Then the continuity of $f$ at $a$ assures that we can find some $x_1\in(a,b)$ satisfying $f(x_1)>f(x_0)$.

So the assumption leads to a contradiction and we conclude that $f(a)\leq\max_{x\in(a,b)}f(x)$.

Same story for $b$.